# serverless and alamofire "User is not authorized to access this resource" but works with postman

Tags: swift, lambda, alamofire, serverless-framework, serverless

I am getting an error that I haven't been able to solve. From my serverless function only through iOS (Alamofire). I have about 15 functions and this is only happening on two. The rest of the functions are working fine.

> {"Message":"User is not authorized to access this resource"}

It works fine when I am using postman.

I am using tokens but all the other functions are working is the same way. It also wont nessicerly be a serverless permissions error, becuase it is working through post man.

Here is the basic Alamofire code. I am using a request adaptor for the headers.

```
Alamofire
        .request(url, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<500)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference in the future:

I sort of found my answer. I don't have time at the moment to dig much deeper. It was to do with the permissions of my custom auth function not allowing the specific Arn to go through even though it was setting it. So all I did was put an '*' for now rather than the specific arns for the functions.

```
const generatePolicy = (principalId, effect, resource) => {
  const authResponse = {};
  authResponse.principalId = principalId;
  if (effect && resource) {
    const policyDocument = {};
    policyDocument.Version = "2012-10-17";
    policyDocument.Statement = [];
    const statementOne = {};
    statementOne.Action = "execute-api:Invoke";
    statementOne.Effect = effect;
    statementOne.Resource = resource;
    policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
    authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
  }
  return authResponse;
};
```

and called it like this

```
generatePolicy(val.id, "Allow", "*")
```

instead of passing the methodArn

```
const { authorizationToken, methodArn } = event;
generatePolicy(val.id, "Allow", methodArn)
```

Not the safest but I will fix it up latter.